# How do I create a shortcut to a particular session in Beyond Compare?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I am using the folder and  file comparison tool "Beyond Compare"

I have a number of sessions stored and would like to be able to create shortcuts that point directly to the sessions.  The program does offer command line support, and I'm able to create a batch file to launch the desired sessions, but it just feels archaic to do it that way.

Does anyone know of a way to create a shortcut that will launch a particular session, preferably with the ability to launch more than one at a time, without using a command prompt to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond Compare will open a saved session if you pass it as a command line argument.

```
bcompare.exe "saved session number 1"
```

To create a shortcut that launches a saved session:

1. Right click and drag BCompare.exe onto your desktop, then select
   **Create shortcuts here**.
2. Right click on the shortcut and select **Properties**.
3. In the **Shortcut** tab, set **Target**:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe" "saved session number 1"
   ```